# How to Concatenate the output of multiple Queries output based on a specific column?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have multiple queries in the following format:

Query 1:

```
Select id,first_name,middle_name
from table1
where id < 4
```

Output 1:

| id | first_name | middle_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Linda | Marie |
| 2 | Mary | Alice |
| 3 | John | Steven |

Query 2:

```
Select id,last_name
from table2
where id < 4
```

Output 2:
Contains optional column (Last Name), which means it doesn't show for all entries, only if it has a value.

| id | last_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jackson |
| 3 | Thomson |

---

How do I get the following?
The ID column the common and correctly associate the different outputs.

| id | first_name | middle_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Linda | Marie | Jackson |
| 2 | Mary | Alice | NULL |
| 3 | John | Steven | Thomson |

---

---

More complicated situation

Table1

| id | Entry | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first_name | Linda |
| 2 | first_name | Mary |
| 3 | first_name | John |
| 1 | second_name | Liam |
| 2 | second_name | Violet |
| 3 | second_name | Charlotte |

Table2

| id | Entry | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | middle_name | Marie |
| 2 | middle_name | Alice |
| 3 | middle_name | Steven |
| 1 | last_name | Jackson |
| 3 | last_name | Thomson |

Desired output is still

| id | first_name | middle_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Linda | Marie | Jackson |
| 2 | Mary | Alice | NULL |
| 3 | John | Steven | Thomson |

Comment: LEFT JOIN to table2 and optionally coalesce.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to write it ? @Isolated

Comment: Added answer below. Also, no need to `concatenate` here.

Comment: Can table2 contain id's not existing in table1?

Comment: If your question leads to a more complicated question ***please do not materially change the existing question***, that invalidates existing comments and answers. Instead, please raise a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just LEFT JOIN to table2.

```
select a.id, a.first_name, a.middle_name, b.last_name
from table1 a
left join table2 b
  on a.id = b.id
where a.id < 4
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your recent edit to the question, you can use `conditional aggregation` to achieve those updated results.

```
select 
 a.id, 
 max(case when a.entry = 'first_name' then a.result end) as first_name,
 max(case when b.entry = 'middle_name' then b.result end) as middle_name, 
 max(case when b.entry = 'last_name' then b.result end) as last_name
from table1 a
left join table2 b
  on a.id = b.id
group by a.id;
```

| id | first_name | middle_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Linda | Marie | Jackson |
| 2 | Mary | Alice |  |
| 3 | John | Steven | Thomson |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dLmZiv2aq1Rp8pQUnkUvxB/0)

Comment: I added a more complicated situation in the question, Can you help with it ?

Comment: @Chris Just updated to address this additional question.

Comment: I'd union the tables before aggregation, rather than joining them.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oETZCCXtXEmdFQQNpaRmsE/0

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `LEFT JOIN` :

```
Select t1.id, t1.first_name, t1.middle_name, t2.last_name
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.id < 4
```

---

Based on your recent edit, the structure of data have been changed to entity–attribute–value model (EAV).

I also used conditional aggregation but applied to table2 only to get middle and last names :

```
select t1.*, t2.middle_name, t2.last_name
from (
  select id, result as first_name
  from table1
  where entry = 'first_name'
) as t1
left join (
  select id, max(case when entry = 'middle_name' then result end) as middle_name,
             max(case when entry = 'last_name' then result end) as last_name
  from table2
  group by id
) as t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oLoNp4LtoAzb93vdDqVBb4/0)

Comment: I added a more complicated situation in the question, Can you help with it ?

Comment: Can you check my recent update